# How would I pull this text

Tags: html, vba, excel, innertext

I'm looking at this webpage -> https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&tracknumbers=671299425542&locale=en_US&cntry_code=us

And I want to return the delivered date Thu 3/31/2016 12:16 pm

Here is my code so far

```
Public Sub FedExTracking()

Dim IE As Object
Dim ReturnValue As Object
Dim ProUrl As String
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim PullText As String
Dim iCounter As Integer

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

RowCount = 0

Do While Not ActiveCell.Offset(RowCount, -1).Value = ""

ProUrl = "https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&tracknumbers=" & ActiveCell.Offset(RowCount, -1).Value & "&locale=en_US&cntry_code=us"

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate ProUrl
    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
End With


iCounter = 0
Do While iCounter < 8
    WaitHalfSec
    iCounter = iCounter + 1
Loop


set ReturnValue = IE.document.getElementsClassName("snapshotController_date.dest")(0)

'THIS LINE RETURNS RUN TIME ERROR "91" OBJECT VARIABLE OR WITH BLOCK VARIABLE NOT SET
PullText = ReturnValue.innertext

ActiveCell.Offset(RowCount).Value = PullText & "."

RowCount = RowCount + 1

Loop

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

End Sub

Sub WaitHalfSec()
Dim t As Single
t = Timer + 1 / 2
    Do Until t < Timer: DoEvents: Loop
End Sub
```

I was able to get locate and store the line it seems as long as I'm not tyring to get to the innertext. How would I go about returning date on this line?

< div  class = "snapshotController_date.dest" > Thu  3/31/2016 12:16 pm < / div >

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: And there's not going to be a space in `"snapshotController_date dest"`.

Comment: I wasn't sure because when you scroll over it it's date.dest, but the actual text has a space or at least it looks like it. Thank you though. I fixed that and I'm still returning the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
ReturnValue = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("snapshotController_date.dest")(0).innerText
```

Even though the class name appears to have a space when you inspect it, if you look in the DOM explorer it has a period there instead. Also it's the class name, not the ID so you need to use the `getElementsByClassName()` method and use the HTMLCollection object that it returns.

Comment: Could you explain to me what you mean by "use the HTMLCollection object that it returns". I've seen some other examples of things like HTMLObjectElement, but that doesn't seem to act like a type on my excel. I do have html object library in my references.

Comment: The `getElementsByClassName()` method returns a _collection_ of elements (kind of like an array) because there may be more than one element that has this class. Becuase of this, you either have to iterate over the collection and find the item you're looking for - or in this case it looks like the first element with that class so I've accessed it directly by using `(0)` after the method. Does that help?

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I'm editing the original question for another error that's being returned on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working. Just putting the answer out there for anyone that needs it.

```
Public Sub FedExTrackingWorking()
Dim ie As Object
Dim ProURL As String
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim RowCount As Integer

RowCount = 0

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

Do While Not ActiveCell.Offset(RowCount, -1).Value = ""

ProURL = "https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&tracknumbers=" & ActiveCell.Offset(RowCount, -1).Value & "&locale=en_US&cntry_code=us"

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate ProURL
    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
End With

iCounter = 0
Do While iCounter < 8
    WaitHalfSec
    iCounter = iCounter + 1
Loop

Set htmlColl = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")

For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
    If htmlInput.className = "snapshotController_date dest" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(RowCount).Value = htmlInput.innerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next htmlInput

RowCount = RowCount + 1

Loop

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing

End Sub

Sub WaitHalfSec()
    Dim t As Single
    t = Timer + 1 / 2
        Do Until t < Timer: DoEvents: Loop
End Sub
```